# fancybox 2 iframe size does not change

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm using fancybox to open external urls.
I tired this code for fancybox-html class a href:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".fancybox-html").fancybox({
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '90%',
    height      : '90%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/js/jquery.pageslide.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/js/autocomplete.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/js/overlay.js"></script> -->

    <!-- FancyBox -->
    <link href="http://localhost:8000/media/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/media/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
```

this did not work, the iframe opens in different dimensions like it ignores my settings.
is it possible to debug it?

maybe I'm missing some libraries.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to download the last fancybox to be sure.
Include the js and the css into your page then, try to use this code if is an iframe.
If doesn't work post your html please to see if you have an error

```
     $(".fancybox-html").fancybox({ 
width    : '75%', 
height   : '75%', 
autoSize    : false, 
closeClick  : false, 
fitToView   : false, 
openEffect  : 'none', 
closeEffect : 'none', 
type : 'iframe' 
});


<a href="yourpage.php" class="fancybox-html">test test</a>
```

Comment: ok insert the html iframe and the link to call it please. Return some error in your console?

Comment: It seems that this does work on Chrome.
On firefox on the other hand this did not work - the iframe dimensions stay the same.
any idea why?

Comment: In addition, since I'm opening extrnal urls (none of my control)
is it possible to tell fancybox to auto select the iframe width to capture all content so the user wont have to scroll?

Comment: thanks, would you mind to explain what this does?
(I have not tried it yet)

Comment: simply you have a div hidden and when you click on the link the div appear inside the fancybox like a popup. I hope that this can help you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20529/discussion-between-user1537701-and-alessandro-minoccheri)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".fancybox-html").fancybox({
    fitToView   : false,
    frameWidth  : '90%',
    frameHeight : '90%',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
    });
});
```