# FancyBox iframe is not responsive on mobile devices (Magento)

Tags: jquery, magento, iframe, responsive-design, fancybox

I created an iframe with FancyBox (on Magento), but there is a responsive layout problem when I see the page from a mobile device:
right before the lightbox (named "scegli il colore"), there is a select where users first choose an option and only then they should open the lightbox. The thing is, that the browser automatically zoom the page, so when you click on the lightbox it appears full with, but not the content in the iframe. Is there any way how to set this? These are the setting that I insert inside magento configuration:

```
jQuery("a[rel=iframeLink]").fancybox({
    'type' : 'iframe',
    'showNavArrows' :  false,
    'width' : 1120,
    'height' : 600,
    'mouseWheel' : false
});
```

I tried also with `fitToView: true`, but it showed me no different result.

Page url: http://www.arredodesignonline.com/it/pouf-sacco-poltrona-wasit.html

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13686431/fancybox-2-iframe-size-does-not-change

Comment: Already tried but it's not working...